# Find the radius of convergence for the Taylor series of $f(z)$ at $z=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let , $$f(z)=\frac{z}{\sin (z^2+z)}.$$
>
> $(1)$ Define $f(0)$ so that $f$ becomes analytic  at $z=0$.
>
> $(2)$ Find the radius of convergence for the Taylor series of $f(z)$ at $z=0$.

First part is done. If we define $f(0)=1$ then $f$ becomes analytic.

Now Taylor series expansion is $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ , where , $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$. From here how we find $a_n$ ?

Comment: Don't pay any attention to that $f^{(n)}/n!$ stuff. The radius of convergence is clear from general theorems about holomorphic functions having power series and power series being holomorphic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since both the numerator and denominator are holomorphic, the only time it can't be is when the denominator is zero (but the numerator is not). Find the smallest $z$ that does this.

Comment: So , $z^2+z=\pi$ ?

Comment: Or $-\pi$, yes.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x+x^2)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x+x^2}\cdot\frac{x+x^2}{\sin(x+x^2)}=1$$
and the radius of convergence of the Taylor series in $x=0$ is given by the distance from the origin of the closest singularity. $\sin(z)$ vanishes only for $z\in \pi\mathbb{Z}$, hence:

$$ \rho = \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4\pi}}{2}=1.34162771851\ldots$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Let us firstly compute $f'(0).$ We have $f'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z-\sin(z^2+z)}{z \sin(z^2+z)}.$ Since $\sin(z^2+z)=z^2+z+o(z)$ then $a_1=f'(0)=1.$
We have $$f'(z)=\frac{\sin(z^2+z)-z(2z+1)\cos(z^2+z)}{\sin^2(z^2+z)}.$$ Try to find recurrence formula to get the expression of $f^{(n)}(z)$ for each $z$ different from $0$ and take the limit after  that of $z$ to $0.$

Comment: That does not give a really effective way for computing the radius of convergence. It is not an easy task to compute $f^{(n)}(0)$ in closed form.

Comment: "Try to find recurrence formula to get..." Did you do it yourself? Then why give this order?